# Linear motion to rotary motion, design

Tags: electrical

How can I convert the linear motion to rotary motion?

The linear force is from a solenoid. Below is my design:

[image: my current design]

The axle goes perpendicular to the plane of paper.
The axle needs to be rotated by an angle of 90 degree with a max torque of 1 KG-cm.

Joint 1 & 2 allow arms to move freely. The solenoid gives a linear motion of 1.5 cm.

I haven't built the prototype. **I would like to know if there is a better design.**

Also what should be the optimal length(in cm) of arms?

Of course a rotary solenoid connected to the axle will work.

I would like a cheap solution, also linear solenoid can be easily made.

Comment: I believe this question is off topic for Home Improvement.

Comment: The piston, arm and crank is a classic solution...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about linkage design.

Comment: Optimizing "length of arms" depends entirely on what force you need and what force you have and how much rotation you require. This design also appears to be likely to need a bearing constraining the solenoid plunger as it will have a force applied by the linkage tending to tilt it in the bore, causing wear and friction. The "simple" answer is to start with rotary motion, i.e. a stepper motor, if that's what you need.

Comment: Whether on or off-topic for Home Improvement may depend on what you are trying to actually do. And wherever this ends up, more details will be needed. Starting with: How big/fast/etc.? How heavy and how large is the load to be moved (rotated)? How fast will it move? How much will it move (e.g., multiple rotations or just one rotation or fraction thereof)? What is the power source? etc.

Comment: @Ecnerwal    I have updated the Question

Comment: @manassehkatz  I have updated the Question